# Java; Multiple MVC and Swing Relationships Best Practice?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I am attempting to develop a "Person database" Java Swing application, using MVC design paradigm with Observer/Observable. Here is a simplified abstract of M/V/Cs I am using:

```
App
    AppModel
        (Empty right now, possibly i'll store certain static application info such as version number here)
    AppView
        (Creates a JFrame and a few other Swing components)
    AppController
        (Instantiates AppModel, AppView and also a PersonController and a PersonListController)

Person

    PersonModel
        (Stores info for 1 person)

    PersonView
        (Displays a number of form fields inside a JPanel (i.e Name, Age, Phone number). Observes PersonModel.)

    PersonController
        (Instantiates PersonView. Observes PersonView. Instantiates PersonModel. Updates PersonModel.)

PersonList

    PersonListModel
        (Stores a list of Persons)

    PersonListView
        (Displays a list of persons with appropriate Add / Delete buttons. Observes PersonList.)

    PersonListController
        (Instantiates PersonListView. Observes PersonListView. Instantiates PersonListModel. Updates PersonListModel)
```

Also, a 'bootstrap', where the app starts. It creates a new AppController.

In the real application, there will be more (and different) Model/View/Controller objects but I want to keep this example simple.

I dont understand how I can go about 'merging' these seperate views into one UI while maintaining a good seperation of concerns.

Take for example the PersonListView. IMHO it doesn't need to care about the AppView (with the JFrame etc). PersonListView just needs to look at its *own* model and update *itself* accordingly. However, I cannot enforce that because the PersonListView's own Swing components need to be added to the Swing components of another view, the AppView.

So at the moment the AppController is instantiating its own View, plus indirectly a PersonView and PersonListView (via instantiation of their controllers). AppController then grabs the 'main' Jpanel for each view, grabs the 'parent' Swing components they should be added to on the AppView, and adds them.

This just doesnt seem the right way to do it to me. Im pulling Swing-related members from their hiding places and messing with them around inside a controller. In fact instantiating the model and view within the controller seems bad too, but I cant figure out a better way.

I've seen enough 'simple MVC' tutorials recently that I'm dreaming of the bloody things - but not one tutorial seems to go into the relationships of multiple models, views, controllers, especially where it concerns Swing. Maybe I am wrong and the App should have just one view? Maybe I need a 'Relationship' class that sort of takes every single Model/View/Controller and instantiates stuff appropriately?

Any advice would be most appreciated as Im completely at a loss!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where a strict MVC paradigm falls down (in Swing anyway, and it may explains why Swing is written the way it is).

Swing combines the view and control elements together, leaving the model separate. That means, you are free to add a view to any other view and the control follows (the model remains dynamic).

I have a developer who insists on using the strict approach to MVC and they still can't tell me the order of precedence. ie should the control know about the view or should the view know about the control - which one plugins into the other. Personally, I'm to lazy and simply follow the Swing implementation.

To my mind, if you want to follow a strict MVC, I'd basically allow for a public method in your controller that allows access to the overall view (say a `JPanel` with all the components on it that makes up the view for example).

Think about the `JComboBox` or `JSpinner` for example.  They both have a number of components that make up the view (editors, buttons, etc), but you have single access point, the component itself...

Your next problem is going to be how to combine various views into a single over all view.

Personally, I would create a group controller of some kind that allowed you to supply the various, known, controllers together (`setPersonList` for example), as the "master" controller is going to need to know about these other controllers any way, as it needs to know how to layout them out.

IMHO

Comment: Thanks for your input, I'm going to try and implement a group controller like you suggest. I think I'll make it instantiate all MVCs in the program right there, then have it attach the Swing components of each view together as required.